# Stream a video stored on AWS S3 from an Android app

Tags: android, amazon-s3, video-streaming, media-player

I have checked the similar questions but they did not seem to solve the purpose hence asking the question along with the code logic.

I am able to get a REST url from S3 of format :  https://s3.amazonaws.com/{bucket}/file.MOV?Signature=xyz&Expires=abc&AWSAccessKeyId=lmn

Now I need the Media player to play(stream) this video.

My Code :

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

try {
        mp.setDataSource(urlS3REST);
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
    }
catch{...}
```

The Error thrown here is : Prepare failed. : status=0x105

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

const PVMFStatus PVMFErrRTSP458ParameterIsReadOnly = (-105);
You might not have permission to write to the file,Files can only be read.

Comment: How is this even an answer dude?